# Accessing parameters of the same name of different classes in Scala

Tags: scala, private, public

I have a very specific scenario, in which I have some different abstract classes the have child case classes that can have different parameters, for example:

```
abstract class ball() {}

case class football(_name: String, _shape: String) extends ball

case class basketball(_name: String, _size: Int) extends ball
```

and a different abstract class:

```
abstract class food() {}

case class vegetarian(_name: String, calories: Int) extends food

case class meat(_name: String, proteinCount: Int) extends food
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is that I need to somehow extract the name of all of those without knowing what class it is, I just know that ALWAYS, EACH CLASS has a parameters named `_name`.

Supposing we have an `object` of any of above classes, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
object.getClass.getDeclaredField("_name").get(this)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
can not access a member of class package.food with modifiers "private"
```

I tried putting val and var before parameters in class but it doesnt help. I also tried doing "setAccessible(true)" in a line before get(this), which also doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious clean solution would be to have a least a common trait to all these classes:

```
trait HasName {
  def _name: String
}
```

and then you can safely do `obj.asInstanceOf[HasName]._name`. Better yet if you manage to keep around the static information that `obj` is a `HasName`, in which case `obj._name` suffices.

If you can't do any of that, reflection is the way to go. You can do it pretty easily using a structural type, in this case:

```
obj.asInstanceOf[{ def _name: String }]._name
```

Note that this will be slower than the above `HasName` solution, and completely unchecked at compile time.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly how the second solution works? I copied it and it worked in my project, but I don't understand it fully.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, how to implement a similar solution to the method of the same name?

Comment: The scalac compiler implements calls to methods of structural types using Java reflection (at least, on the JVM). Something like `obj.getClass.getMethod("_name", classOf[String]).invoke(obj)`, to give a simplified idea.